# Logging a message and the stack trace of caught exceptions

Tags: java, spring

Using [Spring's JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) to load a specific object by ID if exists, I have this code:

```
Person person = null;
try {
    person = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{ id }, new PersonMapper());
} catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
    LOGGER.warn("Could not find person with id " + id);
}
```

A [Sonar rule (squid:S1166)](https://sourcesup.renater.fr/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1166?layout=false) complains about this piece of code, basically saying that logging a message is not enough, I should also log the exception. But in this case, I don't see the point. Adding the exception as a 2nd parameter to the logger will put a completely pointless stack trace in my logs that doesn't contain anything that I don't already know.

Would you agree that this is a false positive or am I missing something? Or is there another way of writing this code that complies better with Sonar or code quality analysis tools in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what your `PersonMapper` does and there is no way it could generate a `null` instance based on a existing row, you could extract this code differently.

```
private Person execute(String sql, String id) {
    try {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{ id }, new PersonMapper());
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        LOGGER.warn("A smart error message based on sql " + id);
        return null;
    }
}
```

That is still not going to help you with your original question except now you can remove that logger and put it in the caller since you'll have to check if the result is non null.

If you want to keep this code as is, this is a false positive simply because SonarQube can't figure out that you are catching a very specific exception type and that the nested cause is not relevant.

Answer (score 5):

I agree it’s a false positive. Sonarqube is way too strict on this issue in my view and creates many false positives with that rule. Often, when catching a specific exception, we know exactly where it came from.

For this rule, I gave in and logged the exception on `TRACE` in addition to what I already logged at whatever different level. Sonarqube is satisfied, and the log stays clean unless you explicitly ask for verbose output.